# TFS 2015 Express configuration keeps finding older SQL Server

Tags: tfs

I need to install Team Foundation Server Express 2015.

- I have SQL Server 2005 Installed
- I have SQL Server 2008 Express Installed
- I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Installed
- I have SQL Server 2012 Installed
- I have SQL Server 2014 Express Installed

The problem is that TFS 2015 keeps trying to use the SQL Server 2008 Express as a database server and I don't want to upgrade that installation.

How do I setup my TFS to use the SQL Server 2014 Express as the SQL provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is designed to install SQL Express as part of the install. It's Express because it sets everything up and is designed to be run on an empty server.

You could try turning off all the other SQL Instances during the install. That might trick TFS into picking the right one.

Or, the right way, would be to pick "advanced" configuration and choose the SQL Instance that you want to use when prompted.

Comment: I didn't find an advanced configuration anywhere, however, shutting down the other instances of express did help reconfigure the server.